# How to convert .Net comments in RST format into HTML?

Tags: c#, .net, documentation, restructuredtext

In Linux there're many tools to read and convert the comments in code into a HTML/PDF document. I am now working on a .Net project, and I am wondering if we have similar tools to convert the comments in .Net code into a HTML/PDF document?

I tried Google, but did not give me any useful result :( Maybe I am not search with the right keywords.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might want to look at Sandcastle: http://broadcast.oreilly.com/2010/09/build-html-documentation-for-y.html

Sandcastle is a tool that generates HTML / Visual Studio help bundles based on your code comments and actual code itself.

It's relatively easy to use once you get it set up.

But beware! Big projects can cause OutOfMemoryExceptions.

Comment: looks like the project renamed and moved to **https://shfb.codeplex.com/**